# How to query all boards with a specific workspace in Monday Api?

Tags: monday.com

I want to list all boards from a specific workspace?..How to correctly write such query

I am doing this way

```
query {
boards (workspace_id :1405052) {
name
}
}
```

Getting this error

"errors": [
{
"message": "Field 'boards' doesn't accept argument 'workspace_id'",

Answer (score 0):

query {
boards {
id
workspace_id
}
}

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "ids" and not "workspace_id "
try this:
query {
boards (ids: 1405052) {
name
}
}

*Have a nice day!*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

See this [thread](https://community.monday.com/t/query-all-boards-within-a-specific-workspace/9138/8) that states that it is not yet directly implemented.
This is how they expect you to do it:
"That said, you can query all boards within your account, fetch the workspace ID that they are placed in, and then filter those out in your application’s code"